# Get all system Windows values(with prefix)

Tags: windows, cmd, set, system

I know that in Windows exist command SET

cmd-> set

I may show all val system+users.

But I know that in system exist many val with prefix or double prefix (COMPAT_LAYER %**CD**%
)

SET prefix --does not work!

How can I see all val with prefix ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways of refining the output of set. This will find all variables with _ in them:

```
set | find "_"
```

or to find compat_layer

```
set c
```

or to find all variables starting with w

```
set w
```